# Find $G\left(10^{11}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm

Given a function $G(N)$ defined as

$$G(N)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum _{i=1}^{j} GCD(i,j)$$ where $GCD$ is Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers

If it is known that $G(10)=122$, Find Value of $G(10^{11})$

Source: https://projecteuler.net/problem=625

I dont have any clue but i hope its useful to convert summation as

$$G(N)=122+\sum_{j=11}^{100}\sum_{i=1}^{j} GCD(i,j)$$

Comment: Please avoid *no clue* questions. Assuming that $G(10^{11})$ can be computed without the help of a machine, probably $G$ has something to do with multiplicative functions.

Comment: Source is from Project Euler. Does these type of questions requires programming? i am not sure

Comment: It's the point I am actually suggesting: no, it does not require programming. It requires to identify a multiplicative function.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Can you please link the source in your question?

Comment: $Legend:\\
  \phi () \ \ the\  Euler\  Phi\  function,\\
 d|j \ \ the\  divisors\  of\  j,\\
  \rho|j \ \ the\  primefactors\  of\  j,\\
 k_{\rho} \ \ the\  exponents\ of\ the\ primefactors\  of\  j.$

Comment: Eulers product formula at its finest. For the inner sum use: $\large \sum _{ i=1 }^{ j }{ gcd(i,j) } = \sum_{d|j}d \cdot \phi(\frac{j}{d}) =\\
 =\large\prod_{\rho|j }(\rho+k_{\rho}(\rho -1))\rho ^{k_{\rho }-1}= j \prod_{\rho|j }(1+k_{\rho}-\frac{k_{\rho}}{\rho }).$ Now go on with the outer sum.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{k=1}^{j}\gcd(k,j)$ is [Pillai's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function), which equals $\sum_{d\mid j}d\cdot \varphi(j/d)=j\sum_{d\mid j}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$. 
In particular
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\gcd(k,n) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} n \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{d=1}^{N}\varphi(d)\left\lfloor\tfrac{N}{d}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\tfrac{N}{d}\right\rfloor+1\right)$$
and the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{d=1}^{N}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d^s}$ is pretty well-known, for instance through
$$ \forall s>2,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)} $$
and the [tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem), or summation by parts applied to
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\varphi(n) = \frac{3}{\pi^2}N^2+O\left(N\log N\right).$$
Unluckily we need to derive many terms of such asymptotic behaviours to get an exact value of $G(10^{11})$, and I am too lazy to really do it. Roughly, $G(N)\approx \frac{3}{\pi^2}N^2\log(N+1)$.

It looks like the computation of $G(1000)$ [was asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871282/partial-sums-of-pillais-function).

Comment: Your developement from $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\gcd(k,n)$ to $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d=1}^{N}\varphi(d)\left\lfloor\tfrac{N}{d}\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor\tfrac{N}{d}\right\rfloor+1\right)$ is a beauty. I like it! A nice example of the importance of the floor-function. The running time is reduced from $ O(\frac{n^2+n}{2})$ to $O(n)$.
In Pari/GP with: `G(n)=1/2*sum(d=1,n,eulerphi(d)*floor(n/d)*(floor(n/d)+1));` $G(10^8)$ can be computed in less than 4 minutes on a standard PC single-threaded. For $G(10^{11})$ aproximately 60 hours of computation is needed, wich I don't want to spent.

Comment: Nevertheless [the authors of this problem deliver a guidance to solution](http://goatleaps.xyz/euler/maths/Project-Euler-625.html). It is spoken of a running time $O(n^{3/4})$.
There is also an algorithm addressed, which should give an answer in 80 seconds. However, I can't understand this. Maybe you can have a brief look at it.
I am particularly interested in the subject. So I will offer a reward here, for those who will develop a faster algorithm.

Comment: The described method has a running time $O(n^{3/4})$ for computing $\Phi$ function, and we need to compute $\Phi$ $O(n^{1/2})$ times for $G$ function. Therefore overall running time is $O(n^{5/4})$.

Comment: @didgogns: Thank you for the correction. I wonder, if we can get a method running under one hour with $O(n^{5/4})$. All my attempts to implement this algorithm in Pari/GP have failed so far. If the corresponding sums run only up to $\sqrt N$, I only get correct results if the fractional part of $\sqrt N$ is approximately greater than $1/2$.